# crypt() outcome different between PHP versions

Tags: php, hash

I have to transfer a very old application from an old server with PHP 5.4 to a server with PHP version 5.6.

When using the PHP `crypt()` function outputting data on a server with PHP version 5.4.39 looks like this:

```
$2a$08$suUW14s06.5.us82.$$$$.iOPijt4Dzhwyw.2
```

Which is correct. And a server with PHP version 5.6.16 outputs this:

```
$2a$08$suUW14s06.5.us82.$
```

The code and input data is exactly the same. It looks like the prepended salt is only outputted, but not the given value to hash?

This is the hashing function:

```
function hash($string)
{
    return crypt($string, '$2a$08$' . ENCRYPTION_SALT . '$');
}
```

Where ENCRYPTION_SALT is a 17 character long string:

```
zgUo92vv6.9.ww33.
```

Comment: Show the actual `crypt()` or at least an example

Comment: As you can see in [the changelog of this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php#refsect1-function.crypt-changelog), there were quite some changes between your two versions. probably it has to do something with that?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Function is added

Comment: Are you sure that the system running the new version supports Blowfish in `crypt(3)`?

Comment: Problem is all to do with a salt of less that 22 chars and using a $ in the salt which is not a valid character to exist in a salt for blowfish, see dup answers

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Nothing in the changelogas noted by ArSen seems to show changes for the Blowfish algo

Comment: @RiggsFolly See my updated answer